# Lists from columns from SQLalchemy ResultProxy object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I execute a query like this:

```
query_result = engine.execute(SQLQUERY)
```

and the result is a `ResultProxy` object.

I want two lists corresponding to two columns `A` and `B` in the result. I can do this as follows:

```
result = [[row['A'],row['B']] for row in query_result]
result = (zip(*result))
```

But this seems very inelegant, is there a better way? I can't figure out how to get the `ResultProxy` object to return lists for the values in columns `A` and `B`.

Comment: i guess it is as elegant as it gets, unless you wrap it in a function `get_result_lists_for_columns(columns)`, in which case it would seem even better from outside. Tiny bit you can do is: `result = zip([row.A, row.B] for row in query_result)` in case your columns as ResultProxy supports this.